# form action change based on radio button selection in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, forms

Now i have a form and two radio buttons.
Based on which radio button is selected I have to change my forms action.

here is the code

```
 <form action={{action}} name="payform" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="radio radio-text">
<label>
<input type="radio" ng-model="cash" ng-click="paymethod('cash')" name="payment" value="cash">Cash
</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="radio radio-text">
<label>
<input type="radio" ng-model="online" ng-click="paymethod('online')" name="payment" value="online">Online
</label>
</div>
</div>


<button class="btn btn-success" name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And here is the controller code

```
$scope.paymethod = function(ptype){
alert("hi");
if(ptype=="cash"){
$scope.action = "food.php";
}
else if(ptype=="online"){
$scope.action = "online.php";
}
}
```

I used alert in the function to check if the function is being called or not. And alert is working it means function is being called but when i click submit nothing happens.

Comment: Check wether u r getting ptype or not

Comment: yes i am getting ptype. I checked by printing the value in console

Comment: I can see from the network tab navigating to respective action. Are you seeing any error in console. Please check the console & network of this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/n0pydc8k/

Comment: Thanks. I had a error. Thanks for suggesting

Comment: Please close the question, either by *answering yourself* with your solution or **accept** any of the following answers.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for, but it solves your problem:

- Prepend your form fields ng-models with formData.
- Add ng-submit to your form
- Use that function to place an $http request

Very basic example:

HTML:

```
<form name="payform" ng-submit="submitForm()">
     <input ng-model="formData.value1" />
     <input ng-model="formData.value2" />
     <button type="submit"></submit>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$scope.submitForm = function submitForm() {
    $http.post($scope.ptype + '.php', $scope.formData).then(
        function success(response) {
             // do something
        },
        function error(response) {
             // not good
        }
    };
```

Because of prefixing your form ng-model attributes with formData, you have all fields contained in one object, which you can easily use when placing a POST request.